# Mapbox Studio - View bridges at any zoom

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm currently styling a map with Mapbox Studio. My goal is to get bridges over water to be visible at any zoom. I've tried several different approaches so far.

1. The first and most obvious approach is to work directly with the bridges layers. This works, but the bridges are only visible when the zoom >= 13. There is an option to change this in *select data* for the layers, but that doesn't seem to do anything.
2. Using the roads layer. The roads layer also contains bridges within it, but can't distinguish bridges from roads at < 13 zoom. To get the desired result, the roads layer needs to be in front of the water layer, the water layer needs to be in front of the land layer, and the land layer needs to be in front of the roads layer. Land needs to be behind water, because land does not exclude water. This gives me an impossible configuration. No matter which way I try it, something will be out of place.
3. The only option that I've really found to be somewhat viable thus far is to make the roads layer the same color as the land layer. This then shows bridges over the water and the roads appear hidden on the land.

I'd prefer not to go with my third approach, as I'd like there to be contrast between the bridges and land. I think the most desirable outcome would be using the roads layer, but hiding it while not over water. This way, bridges on land would not appear, but I'm not confident that there's any way to do this.

Is there any way possible to make either of the first two approaches work; or a different approach all together?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the zoom extent floor of the Streets tileset, which is set at 13. According to the Mapbox documentation there are a couple of ways you can edit the tileset to change this value.
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/adjust-tileset-zoom-extent/

Note that only really big bridges are going to be visible at zoom < 13.